# How to send Post request with 4 key values that's in an If statement, within another Post statement

Tags: javascript

Hello I am trying to post 4 key values (weatherDescription, query, temp, imageURL) to a success.ejs file. But these values are within an if statement. Currently they are just sent to a blank HTML doc and i want to CSS the success page. Any tips to accomplish this would be very appreciated!

```
        app.post("/", function(req, res){
        const query = req.body.cityName;
        const unit = "metric";
        const apiKey = "********";
        const url = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?appid=" + 
        apiKey + "&q=" + query + "&units=" + unit;

        https.get(url, function(response){
          console.log(response.statusCode);

          if (response.statusCode === 200) {
            response.on("data", function(data){

              const weatherData =  JSON.parse(data);
              const temp = weatherData.main.temp;
              const weatherDescription = weatherData.weather[0].description;
              const icon = weatherData.weather[0].icon;
              const imageURL = "http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/" + icon + 
              "@2x.png";

              res.write("<p>The weather is currently " + weatherDescription + " 
              </p>");
              res.write("<h1>The temperature in " +  query + " is " + temp + "  
              degrees Celcius.</h1>");
              res.write("<img src=" + imageURL + ">");

              res.send();
            });

          } else {
            res.sendFile(__dirname + "/failure.html");
          }
        });
      });

      app.post("/success", function(req, res){
        res.redirect("/success");
      });

      app.post("/failure", function(req, res) {
        res.redirect("/");
      });
      
      
      In success.ejs:
      
      <p><%= weatherDescription %></p>

      <p><%= query %></p>

      <p><%= temp %></p>

      <p><%= imageURL %></p>
```

Comment: Sounds like you want [res.render()](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.render). FYI, double-quoted strings in JS cannot have newlines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're able to easily send content to an EJS file using res.render's parameters.
For example, you can call res.render with these parameters:

```js
res.render( path.join(__dirname, "success.ejs"), { weatherDescription : weatherDescription, query : query, temp : temp, imageURL : imageURL } );
```

And access them from EJS through:

```js
<p>The weather is currently <%= weatherDescription %></p>
<h1>The temperature in <%= query %> is <%= temp %> degrees Celcius.</h1>
<img src="<%= imageURL %>">
```

If this helped, mark it as an answer. (it probably didnt)